# how to tell if an array includes any of the substrings

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array with javascript strings that looks something like this:

```
let array = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
```

and I have some words inside my string that are separated by a `|` 
this is the string:

```
let string = 'pig|cat|monkey'
```

so how do I know if my array includes at least one of these items within my string?

Comment: Please share your attempt. You could split the string on `"|"` character, then use `array.some` and `array.includes` to check the "at least one" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an animal from the array exists in the string using an Array method `.some()`

```
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
const string = 'pig|cat|monkey'
const splitString = string.split('|')


const hasAnimals = animals.some(animal => splitString.includes(animal))
```

You can get the animals that are present using an Array method `.reduce()`

```
const presentAnimals = splitString.reduce((acc, animal) => {
  const animalExists = animals.includes(animal)
  if (animalExists) {
    acc.push(animal)
  }
  return acc
}, [])
```

Or if you prefer a one liner

```
const presentAnimals = splitString.reduce((acc, animal) => animals.includes(animal) ? [...acc, animal] : [...acc], [])
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` the string by `|` and `trim` the each word.
Use array `includes` to check with `some` word.

```js
const has = (arr, str) =>
  str.split("|").some((word) => arr.includes(word.trim()));

let array = ["cat", "dog", "bird"];
let string = "pig|cat|monkey";

console.log(has(array, string));
console.log(has(array, "rabbit|pig"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using the character `|`, then run a `forEach` loop and check if the value of `parts` is present in the array.

```js
let array = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'monkey'];
let str = 'pig|cat|monkey';
//split the string at the | character
let parts = str.split("|");
//empty variable to hold matching values
let targets = {};
//run a foreach loop and get the value in each iteration of the parts
parts.forEach(function(value, index) {
  //check to see if the array includes the value in each iteration through
  if(array.includes(value)) {
    targets[index] = value; //<-- save the matching values in a new array    
    //Do something with value...
  }
})
console.log(targets);
```

```html
I have an array with javascript strings that looks something like this: let array = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird'] and I have some words inside my string that are separated by a | this is the string: let string = 'pig|cat|monkey' so how do I know if my array
includes at least one of these items within my string?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```js
let array = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird'];

let string = 'ca';

var el = array.find(a =>a.includes(string));

console.log(el);
```