# Search an array of strings with an array of strings parameter

Tags: reactjs

I have the method below that takes an array of strings.
I want to be able to return true if the user has any of the array string passed.

How can I achieve that?

```
      const hasAnyPermission = (permissionsPassed: string[]) => {
        if (user?.permissionsEnabled === false) {
          return true
        }

        //permissions below is an array of strings
        return permissions.includes(permissionsPassed)
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to tell if an array includes any of the substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317072/how-to-tell-if-an-array-includes-any-of-the-substrings)

Comment: there's no other way but to traverse the array.
I recommend to use either a `Map` or a `Set` to check if it includes permissionPassed.
code would be like so : `permissionsPassed.some(permission => permissions.has(permission))`